# Adobe Javascript - Validate items on dropdown

Tags: javascript, pdf, adobe

I have a fillable PDF with a drop-down list of 200 items (strings all in CAPS, i.e. DG114). I would like to have the user (in a tablet) type the item and the item must match one in the drop-down list. I am trying the following:

```
var ans = event.value.toUpperCase();
var res =  this.getField("combo1").value;
if(ans == res) {
event.value = ans;
}
else {
event.value = "NOT FOUND";
}
```

When typed in a tablet, by default, the first letter is CAPS followed by small letters. I am trying go convert to upper case first and make the typed text match either in lower case or upper case. It doesn't seem to work if the user types dg114, but it works if they type DG114.

What am I doing incorrect?

Comment: can you try to convert both `ans` and `res` in upper case and then compare. like` if(ans.toUpperCase() == res.toUpperCase())` and to remove uppercase from `ans` value.

Comment: you should alert ans and res for testing cause your code looks syntactically correct seems something up with how values are getting there this silly little fiddle working like expected  https://jsfiddle.net/d4c0xmau/

Comment: You might also try out different PDF viewers for your tablet, as their JavaScript support varies considerably.